# Android Lists: ListActivity

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-adapter

I am beginner of android and java also. I am trying **ListActivity** but I have a problem. I can not understand this step:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array));
```

My question are:

1. How do work this step(mechanism)?
2. What is <**String**> beside ArrayAdapter?

Answer (score 0):

The statement you pasted here is creating an `ArrayAdapter` for the list on the fly `ArrayAdapter` constructor takes 3 arguments viz: a context or activity, the layout id of the layout you want to use as your row in the list and lastly the array of data values.

But honestly if  looks foreign to you, then I suggest studying Core java Collections first instead of diving into Android.

Answer (score -1):

1.How do work this step(mechanism)?
setListAdapter(object) you need object for this method so you can create object this way-

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

2.What is  beside ArrayAdapter?
It is string type.If you avoid this it can also run-

```
ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Then give some notification-

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - ArrayAdapter is a raw type. References to generic type ArrayAdapter<T> should be 
     parameterized
    - ArrayAdapter is a raw type. References to generic type ArrayAdapter<T> should be 
     parameterized
```

So you need  type